# Почему querySelectorAll не берёт элементы, которые подгружаются с сервера?

Tags: javascript, queryselectorall

[image: кусок кода html, в котором я добавляю сами карточки][image: Код js, который не хочет собирать информацию о карточках]

Почему-то если добавлять карточки таким образом (через js), то querySelectorAll не видит эти карточки, что делать? Пытался по-разному расставлять приоритеты работы скриптов, но ничего не получается. Аттрибут defer тоже пробовал.

Comment: Прикладывайте, пожалуйста, код в текстовом виде, а не в виде скриншотов. см: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120/189027

Comment: "Почему querySelectorAll не берёт элементы, которые подгружаются с сервера?"  ---- а почему он должен видеть элементы, которые могут быть загружены через, например, 10 секунд от того момента, когда querySelectorAll отработал?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Асинхронная функция может выполняться и 0.000001 секунд, а может и 10 минут.
При этом `querySelector` отрабатывает сразу же как скрипт загрузился. Он не сможет никак узнать о тех данных, которые когда-нибудь там через эпохи загрузится.

Правильно будет скорее так:

```
(async function() {
    await getResponse();

    let popups ...
    ...
})()
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное.

Comment: Я так и предполагал, что скрипт срабатывает быстрее, чем подгружается html, я просто не знал как исправить